# How to use Regex.Matches with a start index AND RegexOptions

Tags: c#, regex

There doesn't seem to be a way to specify both RegexOptions and a start index when using Regex.Matches.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8), there is a way to do both individually, but not together.

In the example below, I want `matches` to contain only the second `hEllo` in the string `text`

```cs
string pattern = @"\bhello\b";
string text = "hello world. hEllo";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches;

// matches nothing
matches = r.Matches(text, 5)

// matches the first occurence
matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Is there a different way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can. You should instead instantiate `Regex` using the desired options:

```
Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

and then you can simply use your existing code from the first sample, which should now match since we're using the `IgnoreCase` option:

```
matches = r.Matches(text, 5);
```

[Applicable constructor docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex__ctor_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_)

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/JTZ77750)

Comment: Ah perfect. That's exactly what I wanted. I didn't realize you could specify options in the constructor. Thanks for your help!